# Fill out a spiral matrix

Tags: javascript

I got this question during my interview:

> Given an integer N, output an N x N spiral matrix with integers 1 through N.
>
> Examples: Input:  3
>
> Output: [[1, 2, 3],
>            [8, 9, 4],
>            [7, 6, 5]]
>
> Input: 1
>
> output: matrix filled out as a spiral  [[1]]

```
/*PSEUDO:
rowMin = 0
rowMax = n - 1
colMin = 0
colMax = n - 1
counter = 1
matrix = []
create the matrix:
loop from 0 to n - 1
  array 
  loop from 0 to n-1
    push 0 into array
while rowMin <= rowMax and colMin <= colMax
  loop on rowMin from colMin to colMax.  col
    matrix[rowMin][col] becomes counter++
  rowMin++
  loop on colMax and from rowMin to rowMax.  row
    matrix[row][colMax] becomes counter++
  colMax--
  loop on rowMax from colMax to colMin.  col
    matrix[rowMax][col] becomes counter++
  rowMax--
  loop on colMin from rowMax to rowMin.  row
    matrix[row][colMin] becomes counter++
  colMin++
return matrix
*/


const spiralMatrix = (n) => {
  const matrix = [];
  let rowMin = 0,
    rowMax = n - 1,
    colMin = 0,
    colMax = n - 1,
    counter = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    matrix.push(new Array(n).fill(0));
  }

  while (rowMin <= rowMax && colMin <= colMax) {
    for (let col = colMin; col <= colMax; col++) {
      matrix[rowMin][col] = counter++;
    }
    rowMin++;
    for (let row = rowMin; row <= rowMax; row++) {
      matrix[row][colMax] = counter++;
    }
    colMax--;
    for (let col = colMax; col >= colMin; col--) {
      matrix[rowMax][col] = counter++;
    }
    rowMax--;
    for (let row = rowMax; row >= rowMin; row--) {
      matrix[row][colMin] = counter++;
    }
    colMin++;
  }

  return matrix;
}

console.log(spiralMatrix(10));
```

Comment: it would be interesting to see this problem solved without random access.  Left to right, top to bottom, in the same order you'd output to a terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Seems mostly solid to me. I just have two small remarks:

---

> ```
> const spiralMatrix = (n) => {
> ```

I'm not a big fan of using the arrow syntax here. The arrow syntax is (mostly) used for inline functions. For a "top level" function I'd prefer a normal, more readable (and hoisted) `function` declaration:

```
function spiralMatrix(n) {
```

The only disadvantage I see is that `const` prevents accidental overwriting, which I don't see as an serious problem in this case.

---

And `.fill(0)` during initialization of the arrays is unnecessary.